# How to show comments for an unpublished node

Tags: 7, entities, comments

this is my problem,

- A node is in unpublished state
- The "View own unpublished content" permission is set
- The node author posted a comment on the node, but the comment is not getting rendered in the node page
- The super admin user though can see the comment.

Is this normal in Drupal 7? If so, how can I make those comments visible for the node author?

Hope I can explain my problem, thanks...

Comment: Something like https://drupal.org/project/su_comments maybe?

Comment: Nope, i dont think so, this module is for published node with anonymous user comments/unpublished comments. But my requirement is for unpublished content bt with comment from the author of that node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely remember I had once an issue with viewing unpublished content and the [view_unpublished module](https://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) offered me a better granularity that solved my issue.

Otherwise I would say creating a view showing comments in relation with the node, using a contextual filter nid, and without the filter "content: published" might help.

Comment: The module did the trick. Would u believe, i ran thru that module before like 4-5 times, bt nowhere in their documentation is it written that it also makes the comments visible. So I never thought of installing it. :P But suggested by u, i tried the module nevertheless, and mereley granting the permission for that to see the unpublished node-type did it. Thanks...

Comment: Cool, when I used it the first time I  had a visibility issue as well and tried it hopelessly and it worked too. Good you got it.